# How to close recent apps in Galaxy s5?

Tags: galaxy, s5

I have galaxy s5 the button which close recent apps is disabled it's not working at all. I would like to create an app that do that task is that possible?  Thank you.

Comment: All signs point to yes.

Answer (score 0):

My wife has a galaxy and she has always used the Active Apps widget:

http://www.phonetipsandtricks.com/tips/samsung-galaxy-s5/useful-widget-to-close-all-running-apps-30/

Comment: Thank you dear I got it.